# Why does vector "emplace_back" behave much slower in multiple threads than single threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, stdvector

I'm doing a project that needs to put lots of data into a vector. I found that it was much slower to "emplace_back" about 800,000 data into a vector in multithreaded callback function (about 4.5 seconds) than the single thread with the same work (about 0.04s), I wonder why and how to solve this problem?

My CPU has 18 cores (Xeon E5 2699 v3, 36 threads), 2 * 8G memory, I opened 17 threads, VS2015 release x64, the concurrency visualizer says the CPU has 85% execution and the "emplace_back" has about 98% inclusive samples. I wrote a simple demo to test the performance, the code is shown below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <vector>

/**brief: In the thread callback function, 800,000 emplace_back
* operations were performed on local vector, 
*/

unsigned int __stdcall ThreadFun(PVOID pM)
{
    double stop, start, durationTime;
    int x = 0;
    std::vector<int> indices_v;
    indices_v.reserve(10000000);
    //========= emplace_back  test==============
    start = clock();


    for (; x < 800000; ++x)
    {
        indices_v.emplace_back(7788);
    }
    stop = clock();
    durationTime = ((double)(stop - start)) / CLK_TCK;

    printf("Thread ID %4d ,time: %f\n",
        GetCurrentThreadId(),durationTime);

    return 0;
}
/*
* same tesk with ThreadFun(), but no reserve(1000000)
* still faster then multithread
*/
void SingleThread()
{
    double stop, start, durationTime;
    int x = 0;
    std::vector<int> indices_v;
    //=========emplace_back  test==============
    start = clock();
    for (; x < 800000; ++x)
    {
        indices_v.emplace_back(7788);
    }
    stop = clock();
    durationTime = ((double)(stop - start)) / CLK_TCK;
    //
    printf("Single Thread  time: %f\n", durationTime);
}

int main()
{
    const int ThreadNum = 17;
    //do 800000
    SingleThread();
    printf("\n");
    //===========MultiThreading======================
    HANDLE handle[ThreadNum];

    for (int i = 0; i < ThreadNum; i++)
    {
        handle[i] = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, ThreadFun, NULL, 0, NULL);
    }
    WaitForMultipleObjects(ThreadNum, handle, TRUE, INFINITE);
    Sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Single Thread  time: 0.046000

Thread ID 28580 ,time: 0.050000
Thread ID 25132 ,time: 1.384000
Thread ID 15428 ,time: 3.059000
Thread ID 15964 ,time: 3.556000
Thread ID 17620 ,time: 3.849000
Thread ID 9056 ,time: 3.965000
Thread ID 18300 ,time: 4.191000
Thread ID 13328 ,time: 4.182000
Thread ID 24972 ,time: 4.184000
Thread ID 13352 ,time: 4.174000
Thread ID 29316 ,time: 4.293000
Thread ID 3056 ,time: 4.278000
Thread ID 25016 ,time: 4.111000
Thread ID 13976 ,time: 4.195000
Thread ID  652 ,time: 4.259000
Thread ID 22104 ,time: 4.174000
Thread ID 13772 ,time: 4.148000
```

I expect the time consumed by "emplace_back" in multiple threads should be similar to the  single thread, but it takes much more time then single thread. I want to know why and how to solve it, any help?

Comment: Thinks, I move the reserve  over the start(),and here is the output:Single Thread  time: 0.056000


Thread ID 14256 ,time: 4.358000
Thread ID 27028 ,time: 4.446000
Thread ID 2288 ,time: 4.462000
Thread ID 18232 ,time: 4.513000
Thread ID 13908 ,time: 4.490000
Thread ID 8228 ,time: 4.480000
Thread ID 15960 ,time: 4.401000
Thread ID 9300 ,time: 4.474000
Thread ID 25444 ,time: 4.541000
Thread ID 9716 ,time: 4.405000
Thread ID 11208 ,time: 4.517000
Thread ID 12136 ,time: 4.437000
Thread ID 13724 ,time: 4.381000

Comment: It is not - you are measuring wrong? If you add threads ... well, what'd you expect?

Comment: Do you have 18 physical cores or 18 logical cores?  If its the latter, I suspect having the physical cores switch between threads is killing your cache performance.

Comment: `clock` is a dangerous function to use. On Windows it behaves strangely so what exactly you are measuring is a complete mystery. Use std::chrono to measure wall time or Windows-specific performance counters to measure CPU time.

Comment: Thanks, My cpu has 18 physical cores,  I suppose the 17 threads works parallel should take similar time or a little bit longer to emplace back 800000 data into their own vector compared with Single thread to do same job,  but  17 threads works parallel takes much more time then single thread

Comment: Maybe virtual memory management (paging)?  What happens if you run the tests a second time (within one run)?

Comment: I have translated your code to portable C++ and tested it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac6511016bf5d29a). The results are reasonable. If you have drastically different results with VC++, report a bug to the Microsoft compiler team.

Comment: @n.m.           Thank you！But  unfortunately  , My result is pretty bad:Single Thread  time: 38621
Thread ID 0 Duration time 122356
Thread ID 1 Duration time 3763444
Thread ID 2 Duration time 4167859
Thread ID 3 Duration time 4902445     ,but still thank you all !

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with VC2017, my output is `Single Thread  time: 10346 Thread ID 3 Duration time 7443 Thread ID 1 Duration time 9794 Thread ID 2 Duration time 10264` etc, all times are pretty similar, no x100 discrepancy anywhere.

Comment: BTW do you enable optimisations? 38621us is pretty bad for a big machine like you have. Performance measurements of non-optimised code are totally meaningless.

Comment: @n.m.          no , I have the VS 2015 Community Edition, which seems does not have PGO ? Did you mean that one?  Actually, I'm just getting started with programming,there is so much I need to learn ,forgive me for my ignorance :)

Comment: No, I mean just optimisations, like in /O2.

Comment: @n.m.          yes，I enable the /Ox，My CPU core has a base speed of 2.3 GHz, pretty slow, though it has 18 physical cores

Answer (score 0):

So, having a single thread run the code took 0.048 seconds of CPU time. Running the code 18 times, once with a single thread and then with 17 threads, took 4.479 seconds of CPU time.

Subtracting to see how long the 17 threads took gives 4.431 seconds. That's 0.26 seconds per iteration.

That means that having all your cores running full tilt caused the code to run about 6 times slower. Or, putting it another way, having all your cores trying to get the work done at the same time allowed it to run three times faster.

18 cores are not going to be 18 times as fast as one core. They share caches. They share memory bandwidth. And so on.

A 3X speedup is not terrible but not great. There might be some issues with compiler flags and the like.

Comment: Thanks for your help,but  should't the 17 threads works parallel to push their own 800000 data into their vectors?  Consider they share caches, I suppose the 17  threads  works parallel should take less then 1s,  and  I try to resize(1000000) in   ThreadFun()   ,then use operater[] to save the data, the Multithreading output nearly the same time with single Thread,  sorry my English is very poor  ,I  may be misunderstand what you mean

Comment: @Hymwgk I believe what this answer was trying to get at is that L3 cache is generally shared between cores, so when one core loads a chunk of its vector to operate on it may evict a chunk that another core was using, leading to reduced performance.  The threads also have to share the same limited number of memory channels, so there may be memory I/O contention between them as well as cache contention.

Comment: `clock()` on Windows does **not** measure CPU time, contrary to what the standard requires. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/clock?view=vs-2019